# How to set Autolayout constraints constant generic or device specific?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, autolayout

I have implemented a constraints `IBOutlet`s on one of UI control and I change the value of those constraint's `constant` property at runtime so that I can animate that control's change in frame, as needed.

However I'm facing this issue: when I change the constant it works perfectly on iPhone 5s but when I run the same code with iPhone 6 that constant need a greater numeric value. How I will make it generic where that constant will be take it dynamic size?

**Here's my implementation:**

```
 func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let scrollViewHeight = Float(scrollView.frame.size.height)
    let scrollContentSizeHeight = Float(scrollView.contentSize.height)
    let scrollOffset = Float(scrollView.contentOffset.y)

    if (scrollOffset == 0) {            
        self.mapUpConstraints.constant = 30
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.8) {
          self.view.layoutSubviews()
        }
    }
    else if (scrollOffset + scrollViewHeight <= scrollContentSizeHeight) {
        self.mapUpConstraints.constant = -160
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0) {
            self.view.layoutSubviews()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to set the constants according to the screen size.

Assuming you know that for the iPhone 5 screen your constant is 30, you can calculate the needed constant for iPhone 6 as

```
self.view.bounds.height / (568 / 30)
```

where `self.view` is a view of your `UIViewController`.

Another approach is to change the constraints `multiplier` property. With this approach you will need to figure out the common relations between your UI components on all screen sizes.

You need to choose what suits you and your UI more.